# Java EE / GlassFish - Threads and connections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Scenario:

I have been using Java SE for quite some time, working with threads etc, though I have little experience with Java EE.

I have a 3rd-party Java library that connects to a remote server (at the 3rd-party company). The library creates several threads and is keeping the connection alive by itself.
I am not allowed to open new connections over and over (by creating new instances of the library). I need to keep the same instance of the library which will keep the connection up at all time.

This is quite easy in a Java SE application.

Now, I want to create a web service (perhaps using GlassFish or similar) to use internally at my company to be able to use the functionality of this library with its connection.
In other words, I need a custom remote connection (that is not created by or managed by my code) to be kept alive between request instances.

Question:
Is this possible to achieve? If so, which technology should I take a look at?

Comment: No, it is a proprietary 3rd-party socket connection. I can not use JDBC or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using connection pool.when ever a connection required to remote server, get the connection from this pool instead of instantiating every time.This will help you in maintaing better memory foot print and efficiency.If connection is no longer in use, you can return the connection to pool.

Comment: Well, I am not the one creating the connections. The proprietary library is creating the threads and opening the connections. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: if that is the case, you can call the method in that library but make sure that the call to the methods in library is singleton.what I am trying to say is get a reference to that library object and check whether the connection has already been established.If so, return the same connection(or there is no need of a remote call).else go for a new connection.That way you can efficiently use that library.I am not talking about connection pooling here

Comment: Actually I tried something similar to start with, but it did not work. The threads kept running, but a typo in my code caused it to not work. I found it though, and keeping the library as a static singleton works indeed! The library itself is thread-safe, and I've synchronized the factory method for creating the library initially. For you other readers out there, this is not an optimal solution for sharing resources. It works in my case, but this will not work if you, for example, have several application servers and want to share data between them.

Comment: I know this is old, but rather than using a Singleton pattern in java, you can use the Singleton EJB, and all variables, including the connection will be instance variables (which ensures they are cleaned up properly when the thread is killed).  Then to initialize the connection, you create a function for this, and annotate it with PostConstruct, and in to close the connection, create a function for this, and annotate it PreDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented a similar system, using Tomcat as the Servlet Container and Metro 2.0 as the JAX-WS implementation.  My service maintains socket connections to backend components (implemented in C++) and communicates with them using a proprietary network protocol.

I used a 'Component Manager' thread to manage the high-level communication with the Components (connection establishment, handshaking etc.) and a 'Network Selector' thread that managed the actual communication with the Components.  This 'Network Selector' used asynchronous non-blocking sockets using the [Java Socket Selector](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbClient.html) family of classes - using a single thread to interact with the Socket Selector class is an important point as some Java platforms exhibit bugs when multiple threads are used.

It's working very well so far, so I can tell you that it's certainly possible.  If you require any clarification then please post here or e-mail me (see my profile).

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly quick answer! However, I am in no control of the connections myself. The proprietary library is creating the threads and opening the connections. Actually, these threads seems to keep running between the request instances, but I am not sure how I can share the reference to the instance of the library without it being serialized.

Comment: Oh OK - might be even easier then - perhaps you might need a 'Manager Thread' to manage these connection threads.  The key point being you need to create a thread during initialisation that will manage the backend resources independently of the request/response workflow.

Comment: This might be a working solution, however, UNNI's solution worked as well for _my specific case_ and was even easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a factory maintaining the connections, and then provide it through JNDI in the same way that e.g JDBC connection pools are provided.

You then need to ensure that the connections are returned to said factory and then integrate it in the application server life cycle so that it is pulled up and down programatically.

Note that there is a nasty classloader problem lurking here if you are not careful.  You will have to have a common class to the factory and the clients and if it is not one in the standard runtime library you will need to figure out a way to have it correctly shared unless you want to use reflection to get to the methods.

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn! What is the advantage of sharing the factory with JNDI instead of just keeping it as a static reference? Currently, this seems to work fine. I'm telling the 3rd-party factory to create/drop the connections when the context is initialized/destroyed through a ServletContextListener.

Comment: Depends on if you can expect the pool to exist in the same classloader as your code is running in.  Apparently it works for you :)